# Windows XP login problems - L key doesn't work

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, login

I've just dusted off an old laptop with Windows XP but am unable to login despite knowing the password, as the <kbd>L</kbd> key doesn't work - of course it's part of my password!

I've cleaned the keyboard thoroughly and tried pressing from all angles but it still refuses to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Plug in a usb keyboard?

Comment: Good answer, but I don't have one :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Buy one for $10. http://www.amazon.com/DCT-Factory-Standard-Keyboard-Black/dp/B000IZGI6W

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few ideas:

- Remote desktop (if you haven't disabled it) or VNC (if it was installed)
- External USB or PS/2 keyboard
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> brings up utilities, use the On-Screen Keyboard
- Alt+keycode
- Pop the key off the keyboard and press the key manually
- Are there any other user accounts with different passwords?
- Boot into command prompt with F8, maybe you can transfer your data from there
- Boot off a recovery CD, and burn your data to a CD, or transfer it over a network

There's no limit to the possibilities.

Comment: 1+ Nice trick (the win + u) quite handy...

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround, try turning on Num Lock, then use the numbers on the number pad to enter Alt+108

Comment: thanks, another good sugg, but I'm giving up. I think my keyboard is melting down, Num Lock won't work either :( Time for trip to the laptop doc. thx for your help.