# How to log in to Windows when the L key isn't working?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I just rebooted my Windows 10 PC and can't log in. I am trying to type in my password but it contains the letter L and when I press the <kbd>L</kbd> key nothing appears.

My keyboard was working fine but I thought it might have spontaneously broken so I plugged in another keyboard and it had exactly the same problem!

I have tried checking if the keyboard layout has changed but it hasn't and I can't find any way to bring up an on-screen keyboard.

How do I log in?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a bunch more things without any luck. My issue seemed to be similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/111837/windows-xp-login-problems-l-key-doesnt-work) that was never resolved.

In the end, after a lot of frustration, I realised that some laptops have num pads on their right side. This is a PC and both the keyboards I tried using are PC keyboards without such a feature. However, on a whim, I tried tapping the <kbd>num lock</kbd> key once to turn num lock on. Lo and behold my <kbd>L</kbd>
key was suddenly working again!

I have no idea how this made became enabled but that was the solution I found. There some more explanation about how you're supposed to enable this mode [here](https://altcodeunicode.com/how-to-use-alt-codes/). It doesn't make much sense as both keyboards have full dedicated number pads.

[image]